# OneNote 2016: How to: selected text in a page & subscribe to the onClick event

Tags: com, office-interop, onenote, onenote-api

I want to implement a COM OneNote Add-In (for OneNote Desktop) with the following functionality:

- User selects some text and then clicks the FORMAT button exposed by the add-in: the add-in will format the selected text in some specific way (e.g. surround the text with "<<>>" and change its background and foreground color.
- Later on when the user clicks on a text that was formatted as described above the add-in kicks in and copies the text in clipboard

I am new to COM add-ins, and I wasn't able to find a good API documentation. I've started with VanillaAddIn (https://github.com/OneNoteDev/VanillaAddIn) and now I need to add my functionality. I would really appreciate any help with the following:

1. How to get the selected text from a page?
2. How to subscribe to the OnClick event?
3. Is there a good/decent OneNote API documentation? I found some links but I still hope there is a better one that I missed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get selected text from a page, look at the GetPageContent API. You can see it used here: https://github.com/OneNoteDev/VanillaAddIn/blob/master/VanillaConsole/Program.cs

From the page content xml, you can find some elements that are "selected".

2. OnClick event: There's no way to know when someone clicks on some text on the page, unfortunately.
3. One site that can help with parsing the page content is the OneNote XSD.  Here: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/63/17/0336.OneNoteApplication_2013_xsd.txt

Comment: BTW I just checked in the xsd directly into the VanillaAddin repro. It is under VanillaAddin\Reference

Comment: So there is no way to click on something in the page and fire an action? Don't the Tags do anything when you click on a checkbox for example? Can i decorate my text with a custom tag that i can use to fire an action?

Comment: unfortunately no.